# Is an answer still an answer if it doesn't use programming at all

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

There have been numerous meta questions about "Not an answer" (NAA) and the general consensus has always been that as long as it even tries to answer the question, it is an answer, albeit often a bad one. While I don't disagree, I'd like to know whether this is still the case when the answer doesn't even use programming?

Here's an example (paraphrased to avoid meta effect on the real one):

> Q: How can I make a certain text bold in a document using Word automation?
>
> A: Just open the document in Word, select the text and click on the bold icon!

Is this an answer, and would a NAA flag be applicable here?

Comment: If the question is on topic, and the answer answers the question, I don't see why not.

Comment: The answer hints that the question may be off topic. Check if the question is on topic.

Comment: A couple examples that immediately come to mind where these answers would be valid: Questions about how to use git, using git "doesn't use programming". Questions about how to configure an IDE.

Comment: if the answer is an answer, it's an answer

Comment: The example you present _seems_ to be an answer, but a very poor one. Wouldn't be flaggable as "not an answer", but as always users would be able to user their votes as they saw fit.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not sure that an answer that doesn't use programming can be an answer to a programming question. It is just like one asks how to write a text to a file and the answerer tells them to open a text editor and paste the text.

Comment: @Briam The question certainly was on topic

Comment: @Nick No, no git or IDE configuration involved ;-)

Comment: @KevinB Then your comment seems to be the answer to _my_ question

Comment: @yivi I wasn't sure wether to flag, that's why I asked. But it's definitely downvote-worthy.

Comment: So you are saying that a question about how to do something in an IDE, which is on topic for [main], is therefore impossible to answer unless you provide a method that uses a programmatical solution to alter the application's settings, rather than simply going into the relevant menus? Sounds awful...

Comment: In fact, now I look at my profile, one of my *most upvoted* answers contains no programming, because it literally does tell a user how to enable a feature in the IDE by navigating the menus, yet the answer was about SQL. The answer was the answer, because the user was getting the wrong results because of they hadn't enabled the feature in their menus.

Comment: @Larnu no, that's not what I meant. If the question is about using a tool commonly used by developers, an answer how to just use this tool is perfectly fine. But if the tool itself is not a programming tool this would be different.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking whether a NAA flag is applicable for such answers?

Comment: @Larnu I think I couldn't make myself clear in my comments. I've updated my question with a more concrete example. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @cigien basically yes.

Comment: Nick was just listing examples of the kinds of questions that would get valid answers with no code.

Comment: I might know how to solve a specific problem in one language but not in the language the OP asks for. I might choose to give an answer that generalizes the approach to assist the OP. Sometimes simply knowing how an approach a problem can be a solution. I guess  I would be using programming concepts e.g. key value pairs. Where would that fit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An answer doesn't need to contain programming to be be an answer, no, nor does it need to contain programming to be an on-topic answer.

Yes, Stack Overflow is predominately about programming based questions, but that doesn't mean **everything** must contain programming.

As an example a User is trying to achieve something in a language, however, the results/behaviour they are getting aren't what they expect. They include code that seems to be correct, detail what else they've attempted, but the behaviour doesn't seem to match that of the answers they have read elsewhere (and cited). The question is in fact a great question (well done!).

It turns out that the answer is because they need to enable a specific option in their IDE or OS for the behaviour to occur which isn't enabled by default, and an answer explains how to achieve this by navigating menus in their IDE/OS.

Such an answer *is* an answer. In fact, it's likely very useful to future users too who have the same problem. The fact that it doesn't contain a shred of programming is irrelevant.

---

An answer doesn't *need* to contain programming to be on topic or to be an answer; even if the question is about programming. If the answer addresses the question then it's an answer, end of story...